# Pyparsing pulp error

Tags: python, pyparsing, pulp

When I try installing ManPy I got the following error message:

> error: pyparsing 2.1.4 is installed but pyparsing<=1.9.9 is required
>   by set(['pulp'])

I checked the Pyparsing setup, but I didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an error in the setup.py of PuLP (which apparently is used by ManPy):

```
#hack because pyparsing made version 2 python 3 specific
if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
    pyparsing_ver = 'pyparsing<=1.9.9'
else:
    pyparsing_ver = 'pyparsing>=2.0.0'
```

As of pyparsing 2.0.1, pyparsing was unified to use a single code base for both Py2 and Py3 installs, but using only Py3 constructs that had been backported to 2.7. It took a few version releases to get this all worked out, but pyparsing (since 2.0.3, now at version 2.1.9) is now compatible with Python 2.6 and later.

If you are using a Python version before 2.6, then you would need to install pyparsing 1.5.7, which is the last pre-2.6 compatible version, and no new 1.x releases are planned.

Contact the maintainer of PuLP and see if you can get them to fix up this version testing in their setup.py file.

**UPDATE**:
On closer inspection, I see that PuLP uses a little module called Amply that does the actual expression parsing. I just ran some tests with Amply on my pyparsing 2.1.9 environment, and they run just fine.